# How to summarise integers in a while loop in a range

Tags: python, loops

guys!

I am trying to do assessment task. It requires me to input number of branches for certain subjects ( Chemistry, Computers, Biology, Physics, Arts). Then it asks me to put number of books for these subjects per branch. Then it asks me to calculate the number of books as total and calculate the average. I am almost done with it but there is one last obstacle for me - how to calculate sum of books in these branches and subjects. I would really appreciate if you explain it to me.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

branches = 0
while branches < 1:
  try:
    branches = int(input("Enter branches: "))
  except (ValueError, TypeError):
    print("Number of branches must be an integer")
  else:
    if branches < 1:
      print("Number of branches must be at least 1")



for i in range(branches):
  for category in ["Computer", "Physics", "Chemistry", "Biology", "Arts"]:
    books = -1
    while books < 0:
      try:
        string_branches = str(i+1)
        books = int(input("Enter the number of books for " + category +  " of branch " + string_branches + " :" ))
      except (ValueError, TypeError):
        print("Number of books must be an integer")
      else:
        if books < 0:
          print("Number of books must be at least 1")
        books_total = 0
        books_total = books + books 
books_per_category = books_total  / branches
print("Following the information of all the branches of the main library: ")
print("Total number of books: ",books_total )
print("Average numbers of books per category: ",  books_per_category)
```

The million dollar question is - how to make books add up to total? Believe me i ve tried like bunch of different methods, but they seem not to work.

Maybe i did not define function of something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have done wrong is that you are assigning `0` to `books_total` for every iteration in category. You will need to declare it before reading the input and add the input to it in every iteration.

```
books_total = 0 # init here
for i in range(branches):
  for category in ["Computer", "Physics", "Chemistry", "Biology", "Arts"]:
    books = -1
    while books < 0:
      try:
        string_branches = str(i+1)
        books = int(input("Enter the number of books for " + category +  " of branch " + string_branches + " :" ))
      except (ValueError, TypeError):
        print("Number of books must be an integer")
      else:
        if books < 0:
          print("Number of books must be at least 1")
    books_total += books # add the input to books_total
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you, sir! Works just as it should! It adds up books -i can not imagine i ve spent 6 hours trying to solve this issue -_-

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to give you a more detailed answer on the CLI, how you could clean the code by splitting it up in functions, how you could define your own exceptions, and how you could remove one of your two main loops. Moreover, instead of summing the number as we go, I chose to store every input. For instance, an output could be:

```
{'Computer': [1, 3], # 2 branches with 1 and 3 books
'Physics': [4], # 1 branch with 4 books
 'Chemistry': [2, 3, 2],
 'Biology': [2],
 'Arts': [2]}
```

The code is divided in 3 parts:

1. Exceptions
2. Inputs
3. Main loop

You can define your own exception. You can read e.g. this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/user-defined-exceptions-python-examples/). Moreover, I chose to limit the number of possible retries for a user input to 5. This way, the program always has an end. I defined `RETRIES` in capital letters I usually I would consider this as an imported global variable.

```
#%% Define custom exceptions
RETRIES = 5

class ConsecutiveWrongAnswers(Exception):
    """Exception raised when the users input too many times a wrong answer
    to a query. 

    Attributes:
        retries -- Number of retries
    """

    def __init__(self, retries):
        self.retries = retries
        self.message = f'The input was invalid more than {self.retries} times!'
        super().__init__(self.message)
        
class InvalidBranchNumber(Exception):
    """Exception raised for errors in the branch number input.

    Attributes:
        branch -- invalid branch number.
        message -- explanation of the error.
    """

    def __init__(self, branch, 
                 message="Branch number input should be a positive integer."):
        self.branch = branch
        self.message = message
        super().__init__(self.message)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.branch} -> {self.message}'
    
class InvalidBooksNumber(Exception):
    """Exception raised for errors in the branch number input.

    Attributes:
        books -- invalid books number.
        message -- explanation of the error.
    """

    def __init__(self, branch, 
                 message="Books number input should be a positive integer."):
        self.books = books
        self.message = message
        super().__init__(self.message)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.books} -> {self.message}'
```

Then, I define input functions which will let the user try to enter a valid input up to `RETRIES` times. The input is checked before it is returned.

```
#%% Input functions
def input_branch_number(category, retries=RETRIES):
    
    def check_branch(branch):
        if branch <= 0:
            raise InvalidBranchnNumber(branch)
    
    attempt = 0
    while True:
        attempt += 1
        if attempt > retries:
            raise ConsecutiveWrongAnswers(retries)
        
        try:
            branch = int(input(f'[IN] Branch number for category {category}: '))
            check_branch(branch)
            break
        except (InvalidBranchNumber, ValueError, TypeError):
            print (f"Invalid ID: branch number should be a positive integer.)")
        except:
            raise
    
    return branch

def input_books_number(category, branch_id, retries=RETRIES):
    
    def check_books(books):
        if books <= 0:
            raise InvalidBooksNumber(books)
    
    attempt = 0
    while True:
        attempt += 1
        if attempt > retries:
            raise ConsecutiveWrongAnswers(retries)
        
        try:
            books = int(input(f'[IN] Books number for (category, branch n°) - ({category}, {branch_id}): '))
            check_books(books)
            break
        except (InvalidBooksNumber, ValueError, TypeError):
            print (f"Invalid ID: branch number should be a positive integer.)")
        except:
            raise
    
    return books
```

And finally, the main loop is now a lot simpler to read:

```
#%% Main loop

# Initialize the data structure which will contain the number of books per category and per branch. 
books_logs = dict()

for category in ["Computer", "Physics", "Chemistry", "Biology", "Arts"]:
    # Input the number of branch per category
    branch = input_branch_number(category)
    
    # For each category, initialize an empty list. The list will be filled by the number of books per branch
    books_logs[category] = list()
    for branch_id in range(branch):
        # Input the books for each (category, branch_id)
        books = input_books_number(category, branch_id)
        books_logs[category].append(books)
```

You can now work on the `books_logs` dictionary to sum per branch, per category, or to get the total.

N.B: For string formatting, instead of summing str objects as you did, I suggest you use the python formatting flag which improves readability:

```
f'This is a formatting string with {n_characters} characters and {n_words}.'
```

The element in between `{}` can be anything, it will be evaluated/executed by python. You could have formulas, e.g.

```
k = 2
f'I want to format with leading zeros integer {k} to get {str(k).zfill(3)}'
```

Finally, I chose a very simple data structure, but you can replace the dictionary with another one. Especially, as suggested by Ruthger Righart you could use a pandas dataframe.

Comment: Mathieu, i really appreciate your help! I am so sorry, but i forgot to mention that i am newbie to python and i barely understood the primary concepts of loops and iterations XD This task too me ages so far and i had to ask my classmates and teachers for iterations XD

Comment: @HeorhiyKremlov I could have guessed that much. That's why since your code was also nicely written, with consideration for wrong user inputs, I wanted to give you a bit more options. Try to pick up good practice as soon as possible. An easy one which really improves a piece of code is to split the code into fundamental blocks, functions which is what I did here with the 3 part (4 if we include the checkers functions which in this case I included as subfunctions of the input).

Comment: Upvoted this answer for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly this statement doubles your no of books, which makes it a wrong calculation

```
books_total = books + books
```

you can do:

```
books_total += books
```

and you have to declare `total_books` outside of loop and every time you enter a new book, you add that number to total books.

Comment: Faizan, thank you! I see how the code works now. I ve spent so much time on trying to solve  that -_-

Answer (score 0):

You may want to put your data in a Pandas DataFrame.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pandas as pd

branches = 0
while branches < 1:
  try:
    branches = int(input("Enter branches: "))
  except (ValueError, TypeError):
    print("Number of branches must be an integer")
  else:
    if branches < 1:
      print("Number of branches must be at least 1")


df = pd.DataFrame({})

for i in range(branches):
  for category in ["Computer", "Physics", "Chemistry", "Biology", "Arts"]:  
    books = -1
    while books < 0:
      try:
        string_branches = str(i+1)
        books = int(input("Enter the number of books for " + category +  " of branch " + string_branches + " :" ))
        df[category+string_branches] = pd.Series(books)

      except (ValueError, TypeError):
        print("Number of books must be an integer")
      else:
        if books < 0:
          print("Number of books must be at least 1")
        books_total = 0
        books_total = books + books 
books_per_category = books_total  / branches
print("Following the information of all the branches of the main library: ")
print("Total number of books: ",books_total )
print("Average numbers of books per category: ",  books_per_category)
```

From there you could make different `sum` operations more easily.

```
df.apply(sum, axis=1)
```

Or sum it per category, for example.

```
df['Computer1']+df['Computer2']
```

If you have many branches just use the string ('Computer') to compute the sum across branches:

```
df.loc[:, list(df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(pat = 'Computer')])].apply(sum, axis=1)
```

Comment: Ruthger, thank you for your response, sir! I really appreciate your help:) But i only started learning Python and i just started to understand basic functions like while, for in and if.

Comment: @HeorhiyKremlov: That is no problem, every developer started at some time from zero. Enjoy the journey :-).